# When to update icon badge number in iOS?

Tags: ios, badge, uiapplication

I have a to do list app and I want to show the number of uncompleted tasks in the icon badge.

**My question is:** Should I update the badge number every time the user deletes/adds a new task in the app or only update it when the app is about to enter background mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I respectfully disagree with everyone here :

```
I generally try and code as if the app or phone could crash at any point.
```

Well, make sure your app is crash-proof and you save yourself useless method calls. They're indeed not gonna influence performance a lot, but it's just cumbersome and not nice to read.

You want your code to be clean, small, and efficient.

This question helps :

```
 When does the user see the badge?
```

Well, when he is out of the app. There is your answer. Update the badge when he is about to be able to see it.

You avoid a little overhead and, more importantly, you work when necessary, and not "all the time just in case you worked wrong somewhere else".
I insist on this : don't correct mistakes by doing other mistakes.

You will end up keeping track of your badge count locally (maybe `NSUserDefaults` ?), and updating it in the `AppDelegate` when entering background or leaving the app :) And you're golden !

Comment: Great answer, I though the same. Actually I registered an observer on applicationWillEnterBackground so I can save the to do list items from my ViewController instead of having to reference theam somehow in my AppDelegate. I will do the same for the badge number as well. Thanks!

Comment: If you've done even the simplest app you'll have found that the fundamental APIs you rely on can be unstable between new releases. The user can also force quit at any time. Taking a robust attitude early on protects you from this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do at anytime. It will not affect your app performance.

Answer (score -1):

I generally try and code as if the app or phone could crash at any point.

So to start off with, do it ASAP if it's critical that the number is correct.

If performance becomes an issue, then delay the action (and additionally, re-calculate and update at start-up).

Answer (score -2):

I think the best possible path is to update the badge count when the app is about to enter the background, since there's no reason to update every time you add/delete a task.

So you can call your badge update method on;

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: In the appDelegate, not in every viewWillDisappear.

Comment: In that case you can call '- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application' this method get called when app is about to go to background.